# How to show intermediate progress bar in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-progressbar

[image]

In above image i have 3 fragments(analysis,timetable and my class). i want to show intermediate progress bar in  each section. please help me..

Comment: You can add 3 progressbars in your xml

Answer (score 1):

You can create three linear layout with width and height  equal to fragments width and height .

In each Linear layout add progress bar .

To show progress bar make your fragment visibility gone  and Linear layout with progress  bar visible.

After loading the  data in each fragment you can make  LinearLayout visibility gone and fragment layout visibility visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create chart using a [**library here.**](http://www.android-examples.com/create-bar-chart-graph-using-mpandroidchart-library/)

You can customize it no of bars and other settings.

[image]